# WebGPU render pass benchmark

Tags: typescript, parallel-processing, benchmarking, webgpu

Are ethere any way in WebGPU to measure the execution time of a specific compute pass in a multi-pass pipeline?

I'm expecting to find and objective way to benchmark various compute pass in order to find whitch step is slowing down the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what "multi-pass pipeline" means in WebGPU.

There are 2 types of pipelines in WebGPU. Render pipelines and compute pipelines. Neither have "multiple passes".

If you have and check for and enable the "timestamp-query" feature then you can add timestamps to the beginning and end of a pass.

The steps are

1. check for and enable the "timestamp-query" [feature](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/webgpu-limits-and-features.html)
2. create a `GPUQuerySet` which is an array of queries
3. add a `timestampWrites` section to your renderPassDescriptor or your computePassDescriptor that specifies which querySet to use and which indices in the queryset to write the beginning and ending timestamps for the pass
4. resolve the queries in the querySet by calling `resolveQuerySet`. This copies the query results to a buffer
5. copy the query results buffer to a mappable buffer
6. map the mappable buffer and read the results. Each result is a 64bit unsigned int in nanoseconds

Example:

```css
@import url(https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/resources/webgpu-lesson.css);
html, body {
  margin: 0;       /* remove the default margin          */
  height: 100%;    /* make the html,body fill the page   */
}
canvas {
  display: block;  /* make the canvas act like a block   */
  width: 100%;     /* make the canvas fill its container */
  height: 100%;
}
#info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<pre id="info"></pre>
  
<script type="module">
// WebGPU Timing - Step 1 - Animated
// from https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/webgpu-timing-with-timestamp-w-average.html


import GUI from 'https://webgpufundamentals.org/3rdparty/muigui-0.x.module.js';

// A random number between [min and max)
// With 1 argument it will be [0 to min)
// With no arguments it will be [0 to 1)
const rand = (min, max) => {
  if (min === undefined) {
    min = 0;
    max = 1;
  } else if (max === undefined) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
};

class RollingAverage {
  #total = 0;
  #samples = [];
  #cursor = 0;
  #numSamples;
  constructor(numSamples = 30) {
    this.#numSamples = numSamples;
  }
  addSample(v) {
    this.#total += v - (this.#samples[this.#cursor] || 0);
    this.#samples[this.#cursor] = v;
    this.#cursor = (this.#cursor + 1) % this.#numSamples;
  }
  get() {
    return this.#total / this.#samples.length;
  }
}

const fpsAverage = new RollingAverage();
const jsAverage = new RollingAverage();
const gpuAverage = new RollingAverage();

function createCircleVertices({
  radius = 1,
  numSubdivisions = 24,
  innerRadius = 0,
  startAngle = 0,
  endAngle = Math.PI * 2,
} = {}) {
  // 2 triangles per subdivision, 3 verts per tri
  const numVertices = numSubdivisions * 3 * 2;
  // 2 32-bit values for position (xy) and 1 32-bit value for color (rgb_)
  // The 32-bit color value will be written/read as 4 8-bit values
  const vertexData = new Float32Array(numVertices * (2 + 1));
  const colorData = new Uint8Array(vertexData.buffer);

  let offset = 0;
  let colorOffset = 8;
  const addVertex = (x, y, r, g, b) => {
    vertexData[offset++] = x;
    vertexData[offset++] = y;
    offset += 1;  // skip the color
    colorData[colorOffset++] = r * 255;
    colorData[colorOffset++] = g * 255;
    colorData[colorOffset++] = b * 255;
    colorOffset += 9;  // skip extra byte and the position
  };

  const innerColor = [1, 1, 1];
  const outerColor = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1];

  // 2 vertices per subdivision
  //
  // 0--1 4
  // | / /|
  // |/ / |
  // 2 3--5
  for (let i = 0; i < numSubdivisions; ++i) {
    const angle1 = startAngle + (i + 0) * (endAngle - startAngle) / numSubdivisions;
    const angle2 = startAngle + (i + 1) * (endAngle - startAngle) / numSubdivisions;

    const c1 = Math.cos(angle1);
    const s1 = Math.sin(angle1);
    const c2 = Math.cos(angle2);
    const s2 = Math.sin(angle2);

    // first triangle
    addVertex(c1 * radius, s1 * radius, ...outerColor);
    addVertex(c2 * radius, s2 * radius, ...outerColor);
    addVertex(c1 * innerRadius, s1 * innerRadius, ...innerColor);

    // second triangle
    addVertex(c1 * innerRadius, s1 * innerRadius, ...innerColor);
    addVertex(c2 * radius, s2 * radius, ...outerColor);
    addVertex(c2 * innerRadius, s2 * innerRadius, ...innerColor);
  }

  return {
    vertexData,
    numVertices,
  };
}

async function main() {
  const adapter = await navigator.gpu?.requestAdapter();
  const canTimestamp = adapter.features.has('timestamp-query');
  const device = await adapter?.requestDevice({
    requiredFeatures: [
      ...(canTimestamp ? ['timestamp-query'] : []),
     ],
  });
  if (!device) {
    fail('need a browser that supports WebGPU');
    return;
  }

  // Get a WebGPU context from the canvas and configure it
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext('webgpu');
  const presentationFormat = navigator.gpu.getPreferredCanvasFormat();
  context.configure({
    device,
    format: presentationFormat,
  });

  const module = device.createShaderModule({
    code: `
      struct Vertex {
        @location(0) position: vec2f,
        @location(1) color: vec4f,
        @location(2) offset: vec2f,
        @location(3) scale: vec2f,
        @location(4) perVertexColor: vec3f,
      };

      struct VSOutput {
        @builtin(position) position: vec4f,
        @location(0) color: vec4f,
      };

      @vertex fn vs(
        vert: Vertex,
      ) -> VSOutput {
        var vsOut: VSOutput;
        vsOut.position = vec4f(
            vert.position * vert.scale + vert.offset, 0.0, 1.0);
        vsOut.color = vert.color * vec4f(vert.perVertexColor, 1);
        return vsOut;
      }

      @fragment fn fs(vsOut: VSOutput) -> @location(0) vec4f {
        return vsOut.color;
      }
    `,
  });

  const pipeline = device.createRenderPipeline({
    label: 'per vertex color',
    layout: 'auto',
    vertex: {
      module,
      entryPoint: 'vs',
      buffers: [
        {
          arrayStride: 2 * 4 + 4, // 2 floats, 4 bytes each + 4 bytes
          attributes: [
            {shaderLocation: 0, offset: 0, format: 'float32x2'},  // position
            {shaderLocation: 4, offset: 8, format: 'unorm8x4'},   // perVertexColor
          ],
        },
        {
          arrayStride: 4, // 4 bytes
          stepMode: 'instance',
          attributes: [
            {shaderLocation: 1, offset: 0, format: 'unorm8x4'},   // color
          ],
        },
        {
          arrayStride: 4 * 4, // 4 floats, 4 bytes each
          stepMode: 'instance',
          attributes: [
            {shaderLocation: 2, offset: 0, format: 'float32x2'},  // offset
            {shaderLocation: 3, offset: 8, format: 'float32x2'},  // scale
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    fragment: {
      module,
      entryPoint: 'fs',
      targets: [{ format: presentationFormat }],
    },
  });

  const kNumObjects = 10000;
  const objectInfos = [];

  // create 2 vertex buffers
  const staticUnitSize =
    4;     // color is 4 bytes
  const changingUnitSize =
    2 * 4 + // offset is 2 32bit floats (4bytes each)
    2 * 4;  // scale is 2 32bit floats (4bytes each)
  const staticVertexBufferSize = staticUnitSize * kNumObjects;
  const changingVertexBufferSize = changingUnitSize * kNumObjects;

  const staticVertexBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    label: 'static vertex for objects',
    size: staticVertexBufferSize,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
  });

  const changingVertexBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    label: 'changing storage for objects',
    size: changingVertexBufferSize,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
  });

  // offsets to the various uniform values in float32 indices
  const kColorOffset = 0;

  const kOffsetOffset = 0;
  const kScaleOffset = 2;

  {
    const staticVertexValuesU8 = new Uint8Array(staticVertexBufferSize);
    for (let i = 0; i < kNumObjects; ++i) {
      const staticOffsetU8 = i * staticUnitSize;

      // These are only set once so set them now
      staticVertexValuesU8.set(        // set the color
          [rand() * 255, rand() * 255, rand() * 255, 255],
          staticOffsetU8 + kColorOffset);

      objectInfos.push({
        scale: rand(0.2, 0.5),
        offset: [rand(-0.9, 0.9), rand(-0.9, 0.9)],
        velocity: [rand(-0.1, 0.1), rand(-0.1, 0.1)],
      });
    }
    device.queue.writeBuffer(staticVertexBuffer, 0, staticVertexValuesU8);
  }

  // a typed array we can use to update the changingStorageBuffer
  const vertexValues = new Float32Array(changingVertexBufferSize / 4);

  const { vertexData, numVertices } = createCircleVertices({
    radius: 0.5,
    innerRadius: 0.25,
  });
  const vertexBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    label: 'vertex buffer vertices',
    size: vertexData.byteLength,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
  });
  device.queue.writeBuffer(vertexBuffer, 0, vertexData);

  const { querySet, resolveBuffer, resultBuffer } = (() => {
    if (!canTimestamp) {
      return {};
    }

    const querySet = device.createQuerySet({
       type: 'timestamp',
       count: 2,
    });
    const resolveBuffer = device.createBuffer({
      size: querySet.count * 8,
      usage: GPUBufferUsage.QUERY_RESOLVE | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_SRC,
    });
    const resultBuffer = device.createBuffer({
      size: resolveBuffer.size,
      usage: GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST | GPUBufferUsage.MAP_READ,
    });
    return {querySet, resolveBuffer, resultBuffer };
  })();

  const renderPassDescriptor = {
    label: 'our basic canvas renderPass with timing',
    colorAttachments: [
      {
        // view: <- to be filled out when we render
        clearValue: [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1],
        loadOp: 'clear',
        storeOp: 'store',
      },
    ],
    ...(canTimestamp && {
      timestampWrites: {
        querySet,
        beginningOfPassWriteIndex: 0,
        endOfPassWriteIndex: 1,
      },
    }),
  };

  const infoElem = document.querySelector('#info');
  let gpuTime = 0;

  const settings = {
    numObjects: 100,
  };

  const gui = new GUI();
  gui.add(settings, 'numObjects', 0, kNumObjects, 1);

  const euclideanModulo = (x, a) => x - a * Math.floor(x / a);

  let then = 0;
  function render(now) {
    now *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds
    const deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;

    const startTime = performance.now();

    // Get the current texture from the canvas context and
    // set it as the texture to render to.
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].view =
        context.getCurrentTexture().createView();

    const encoder = device.createCommandEncoder();
    const pass = encoder.beginRenderPass(renderPassDescriptor);
    pass.setPipeline(pipeline);
    pass.setVertexBuffer(0, vertexBuffer);
    pass.setVertexBuffer(1, staticVertexBuffer);
    pass.setVertexBuffer(2, changingVertexBuffer);

    // Set the uniform values in our JavaScript side Float32Array
    const aspect = canvas.width / canvas.height;

    // set the scale and offset for each object
    for (let ndx = 0; ndx < settings.numObjects; ++ndx) {
      const {scale, offset, velocity} = objectInfos[ndx];
      // -1.5 to 1.5
      offset[0] = euclideanModulo(offset[0] + velocity[0] * deltaTime + 1.5, 3) - 1.5;
      offset[1] = euclideanModulo(offset[1] + velocity[1] * deltaTime + 1.5, 3) - 1.5;

      const off = ndx * (changingUnitSize / 4);
      vertexValues.set(offset, off + kOffsetOffset);
      vertexValues.set([scale / aspect, scale], off + kScaleOffset);
    }

    // upload all offsets and scales at once
    device.queue.writeBuffer(
        changingVertexBuffer, 0,
        vertexValues, 0, settings.numObjects * changingUnitSize / 4);

    pass.draw(numVertices, settings.numObjects);

    pass.end();

    if (canTimestamp) {
      encoder.resolveQuerySet(querySet, 0, querySet.count, resolveBuffer, 0);
      if (resultBuffer.mapState === 'unmapped') {
        encoder.copyBufferToBuffer(resolveBuffer, 0, resultBuffer, 0, resultBuffer.size);
      }
    }

    const commandBuffer = encoder.finish();
    device.queue.submit([commandBuffer]);

    if (canTimestamp && resultBuffer.mapState === 'unmapped') {
      resultBuffer.mapAsync(GPUMapMode.READ).then(() => {
        const times = new BigInt64Array(resultBuffer.getMappedRange());
        gpuTime = Number(times[1] - times[0]);
        gpuAverage.addSample(gpuTime / 1000);
        resultBuffer.unmap();
      });
    }

    const jsTime = performance.now() - startTime;

    fpsAverage.addSample(1 / deltaTime);
    jsAverage.addSample(jsTime);

    infoElem.textContent = `\
fps: ${fpsAverage.get().toFixed(1)}
js: ${jsAverage.get().toFixed(1)}ms
gpu: ${canTimestamp ? `${gpuAverage.get().toFixed(1)}µs` : 'N/A'}
`;

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      const canvas = entry.target;
      const width = entry.contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
      const height = entry.contentBoxSize[0].blockSize;
      canvas.width = Math.max(1, Math.min(width, device.limits.maxTextureDimension2D));
      canvas.height = Math.max(1, Math.min(height, device.limits.maxTextureDimension2D));
    }
  });
  observer.observe(canvas);
}

function fail(msg) {
  alert(msg);
}

main();
  
</script>
```

You can read more details [here](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/webgpu-timing.html)

note: you'll probably need to enable "webgpu developer features" in about:flags in Chrome or wait for v121 or v122